# Why are links on my website getting "?pk_vid=" added to them?

Tags: php, html

I noticed that when I view my own website and start clicking links, often they will automatically get "?pk_vid=[ random_hash ]" added to them, in other words https://mywebsite.com/sitemap.php becomes https://mywebsite.com/sitemap.php?pk_vid=e7c1a6e05434662d15564165646fb60f.

The strange thing is also that they are not viewable within the HTML or even hovering over the link itself, only when the link is clicked is it displayed in the address bar. I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this unique circumstance and knew what it is related to.

Comment: we cant see your sites code from here

Comment: looks like a PHP session ID to me...

Comment: There is no code I could post. The only code I could post would literally be ; <a href="sitemap.php">'. For whatever reason, "?pk_vid=...." is being added to that, like I said, not to the HTML, not to the script itself, but only when I click on it. It is as if it's being added after I click on it. It is not being sent through another script, it is not being parsed by any program I am using that I am aware of. The only other thing I can say is it used to only be added to links related to WordPress, or my blog. subdomain. Now I noticed it is being added to all links.

Comment: to Nick, I checked the folder where my PHP Sessions are saved, and none of them match the hash included in the links.

Comment: sorry there is no magic, its your server,code, site.

Answer (score 3):

Are you running Matomo (Piwik)? This may have something to do with Piwik and their cross-domain linking feature.

*The cross domain detection feature works by adding the pk_vid query parameter to every link on the page when it is loaded. This is only done once, so if your webpage or webapp adds links dynamically to the page through JavaScript, they will not have this query parameter added to the URLs.*

https://matomo.org/faq/how-to/faq_23654/

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. That was the answer dearsina.